# How to save information in two different tables in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I have a django application where I can open a form with fields (client and services) rendered (form) and save it in a single table.

I decided to separate the customer data in another table, so as not to have the same customer saved more than once in the services table.

It turns out that I don't know how to apply this reasoning in practice.

Below is the view responsible for the n

ew registration.

```
@login_required
def NovaOS(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrdemServicoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            OS = form.save(commit=False)
            OS.user = request.user
            OS.save()
            return redirect('/os/list/')
    else:
        form = OrdemServicoForm()
        return render(request, 'serviceorders/addos.html', {'form': form})
```

I have already created the necessary information in forms.py and models.py.

forms.py

```
class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clientes
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = { #Dados do cliente
                    'STATUSCliente':                forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Status'}),
                    'cliente_razaosocial':          forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Razão Social', 'autofocus': True}),
                    'cliente_cpfcnpj':              forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'CPF/CNPJ'}),
                    'cliente_rgie':                 forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'RG/I.E.'}),
                    'cliente_email':                forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'E-mail'}),
                    'cliente_telefone_fixo':        forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tel. fixo', 'data-mask':"(00)0000-0000"}),
                    'cliente_telefone_celular':     forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Tel. celular', 'data-mask':"(00)00000-0000"}),
                    'cliente_endereco':             forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Endereço'}),
                    'cliente_endereco_num':         forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Número'}), 
                    'cliente_endereco_CEP':         forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'CEP'}),
                    'cliente_endereco_Bairro':      forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Bairro'}),
                    'cliente_endereco_Cidade':      forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Cidade'}),
                    'cliente_endereco_UF':          forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'UF'}),
                    'cliente_endereco_Complemento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Complemento'}),

        }

        labels = {
            'cliente_razaosocial': 'Nome/Razão social:',
            'cliente_cpfcnpj': 'CPF/CNPJ:',
            'cliente_rgie': 'RG/IE:',
            'cliente_email': 'E-mail:',
            'cliente_telefone_fixo': 'Fixo:',
            'cliente_telefone_celular': 'Celular:',
            'cliente_endereco': 'Endereço:',
            'cliente_endereco_num': 'Num:',
            'cliente_endereco_Complemento': 'Complemento:',
            'cliente_endereco_CEP': 'CEP:',
            'cliente_endereco_Bairro': 'Bairro:',
            'cliente_endereco_Cidade': 'Cidade:',
            'cliente_endereco_UF': 'UF:',
```

models.py

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
    STATUSCliente = (
        ('Ativo', 'Ativo'),        
        ('Inativo', 'Inativo'),
    )

    #Dados Cliente
    cliente_razaosocial          = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cliente_cpfcnpj              = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cliente_rgie                 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cliente_email                = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cliente_telefone_fixo        = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cliente_telefone_celular     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cliente_endereco             = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cliente_endereco_num         = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cliente_endereco_CEP         = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cliente_endereco_Bairro      = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cliente_endereco_Cidade      = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cliente_endereco_UF          = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cliente_endereco_Complemento = models.CharField(max_length=50)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cliente_razaosocial
```

When I change it in the NovaOS view:

```
 else:
        form = OrdemServicoForm()
        return render(request, 'serviceorders/addos.html', {'form': form})
```

For:

```
else:
        form = ClienteForm()
        return render(request, 'serviceorders/addos.html', {'form': form})
```

The fields appear on the form but the previous ones disappear.

What would it be like in practice to place the fields from both tables on the screen and save them in both if the customer and the service order do not exist? What if the customer already exists, just save the service order with the customer ID?

Thank you very much in advance!

I've already tried to change the view, but I haven't found a plausible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can explore formsets to manage  multiple modalForm

```
 # models.py
from django.db import models

class FirstModel(models.Model):
    # Your FirstModel fields go here

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    # Your SecondModel fields go here

# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import FirstModel, SecondModel

class FirstModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FirstModel
        # Your FirstModel form fields go here

class SecondModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SecondModel
        # Your SecondModel form fields go here

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from .models import FirstModel, SecondModel
from .forms import FirstModelForm, SecondModelForm

def manage_multiple_forms(request):
    FirstModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(FirstModel, form=FirstModelForm, extra=1)
    SecondModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(SecondModel, form=SecondModelForm, extra=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_model_formset = FirstModelFormSet(request.POST, prefix='first_model')
        second_model_formset = SecondModelFormSet(request.POST, prefix='second_model')

        if first_model_formset.is_valid() and second_model_formset.is_valid():
            # Save your forms or perform other actions
            first_model_formset.save()
            second_model_formset.save()
    else:
        first_model_formset = FirstModelFormSet(queryset=FirstModel.objects.none(), prefix='first_model')
        second_model_formset = SecondModelFormSet(queryset=SecondModel.objects.none(), prefix='second_model')

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {
        'first_model_formset': first_model_formset,
        'second_model_formset': second_model_formset,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will actually handle a lot of this already.  You just need to have two forms in your template.  If your forms might have a field name in common, you can use `prefix` to keep them clear, as below:

```
@login_required
def NovaOS(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        OSform = OrdemServicoForm(request.POST, prefix="OS")
        Cform = = ClienteForm(request.POST prefix="C")

        if OSform.is_valid and Cform.is_valid():
            //is the cliente new? 
            //filter for existing email, and use first() to return cliente object or None
            cliente= Clientes.object.filter(email = Cform.cleaned_data['email']).first()
            if not cliente:
                 //use Cliente.object.create to return created object
                 cliente = Cliente.object.create(
                      cliente_razaosocial =  Cform.cleaned_data['cliente_razaosocial'],
                      ...

            OS = form.save(commit=False)
            OS.user = request.user
            //As we know now have a cliente object we can add it here
            OS.cliente = cliente
            OS.save()
            return redirect('/os/list/')
    else:
        OSform = OrdemServicoForm(prefix="OS")
        Cform = ClienteForm(prefix="C")
        return render(request, 'serviceorders/addos.html', {'Cform': Cform, 'OSform': OSform})
```

and then in your template

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ Cform.as_p }}
    {{ OSform.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```